# Scheduling using VBA based on Task time and available time for that day

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to schedule tasks based on the time they take and the time available for the different days. Here is the code that is partially working:

```
Sub Scheduling()

Dim Times As Worksheet
Dim tLR, r, c As Long

Set Times = Worksheets("Times")
tLR = Times.Range("C" & Times.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
c = 10
    For r = 18 To tLR
        If Cells(r, 8).Value > Cells(17, c) Then
            If Cells(8, c) > Cells(r, 7) Then
            Cells(r, 9).Value = Cells(17, c).Value
            Cells(r, c).Value = Cells(r, 7).Value
            End If
           End If
        c = c + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

It is not correctly checking the available times and just enters it to the next column that has no times entered on it. I will also give you a screen shot of what is happening.
If you have any queries feel free to ask me.

Thanks in advance for your time helping me.

[image: Screenshot of Worksheet once Macro has ran]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is at least a **start** to fixing your issues:

```
Sub Scheduling()

    Dim Times As Worksheet
    Dim tLR As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    Set Times = Worksheets("Times")
    tLR = Times.Range("C" & Times.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For r = 18 To tLR
        c = 10
        Do While Cells(17, c).Value <> ""
            If Cells(r, 8).Value > Cells(17, c).Value Then
                If Cells(8, c).Value > Cells(r, 7).Value Then
                    Cells(r, 9).Value = Cells(17, c).Value
                    Cells(r, c).Value = Cells(r, 7).Value
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
            c = c + 1
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**Edit - to allow multi-day tasks:**

```
Sub Scheduling()

    Dim Times As Worksheet
    Dim tLR As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim timeReq As Double

    Set Times = Worksheets("Times")
    tLR = Times.Range("C" & Times.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For r = 18 To tLR
        c = 10
        Cells(r, 9).Value = ""
        timeReq = Cells(r, 7).Value
        Do While Cells(17, c).Value <> ""
            If Cells(r, 8).Value > Cells(17, c).Value Then
                If Cells(8, c).Value > 0 Then
                    If Cells(r, 9).Value = "" Then
                        Cells(r, 9).Value = Cells(17, c).Value
                    End If
                    If Cells(8, c).Value >= timeReq Then
                        Cells(r, c).Value = timeReq
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        timeReq = timeReq - Cells(8, c).Value
                        Cells(r, c).Value = Cells(8, c).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            c = c + 1
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

I haven't tested that code, but I think it will be right.

---

**Further edit to allow for maximum per station**

This relies on formulae in cells J9:AF15 which will calculate the available time per station.  For testing purposes I used put a formula in J9 of `=7-SUMIF($F$18:$F$50,$I9,J$18:J$50)` and then copied that to the whole range.

```
Sub Scheduling()

    Dim Times As Worksheet
    Dim tLR As Long, r As Long, c As Long, s As Long
    Dim timeReq As Double
    Dim rng As Range

    Set Times = Worksheets("Times")
    tLR = Times.Range("C" & Times.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 18 To tLR
        'Set row number that contains remaining time for this day for this station
        Set rng = Range("I9:I15").Find(What:=Cells(r, "F").Value)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            'Invalid station entered
            MsgBox "Row " & r & ": Unrecognised station"
        Else
            s = rng.Row
            'Initialise which column to start processing at
            c = 10
            'Reset start date
            Cells(r, 9).Value = ""
            'Set a temporary variable to keep track of how much more
            ' time we need to allocate
            timeReq = Cells(r, "G").Value
            'Loop through each day
            Do While Cells(17, c).Value <> ""
                If Cells(r, "H").Value > Cells(17, c).Value Then
                    If Cells(s, c).Value > 0 Then
                        'Set start date if not already set
                        If Cells(r, "I").Value = "" Then
                            Cells(r, "I").Value = Cells(17, c).Value
                        End If
                        'Check how much time can be used
                        If Cells(s, c).Value >= timeReq Then
                            'We have plenty of time, so assign all to this day
                            Cells(r, c).Value = timeReq
                            'No more to process, so go to the next row
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            'Can't fit everything into this day, so work out how much
                            'we need to carry forward to another day
                            timeReq = timeReq - Cells(s, c).Value
                            'Allocate all remaining time for this day to this task
                            Cells(r, c).Value = Cells(s, c).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    'See if we have hit the due date without yet allocating all the time
                    MsgBox "Row " & r & ": Cannot be scheduled by the due date"
                End If
                'move to the next day
                c = c + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K. That works perfectly! Now I just have to work out have to split a task over more than one day until the task time is used up.

Comment: @Beth - Added an edit to (hopefully) spread tasks over multiple days if required.

Comment: Once again @YowE3K you have got it absolutely perfect! Thank you. May ask your help once again?

Comment: On that screen shot you would have noticed the "Station" column and the corresponding stations below the available time. These are so that tasks that are put for that day do not exceed the station limit. Is it possible to rather than check against the time available for the total day, we work out which station is being used and then what time is available for that station and allocate the time as per above?

Comment: @Beth - It's certainly possible but, unfortunately, my lunch hour is over now and I need to get back to work.  I'll have another look at this question when I get home tonight and, if you haven't left a comment saying that you have worked something out (or someone else has worked it out for you), I will post yet another edit then.

Comment: @beth - One question though - how do we know the maximum time available to each station?  (I see row 8 is just 44 less the **total** time allotted, but there doesn't seem to be anything to indicate the maximum time for each station.  Or are you intending to have formulae in rows 9 to 15 showing how much is available for each station?)

Comment: Yes there will be formula that will calculate the available time for that station.

Comment: Thans a lot for that @YowE3k. I will have to check it when I am back in the office in the morning. Will let you know how it goes.